# I need advice how to structure database for storehouse management with C# MySQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, database

This question is focused on getting an idea how to structure my database. So there is not going to be any code posted. Please don't mark this questions as "too broad" since my case is specific and I need answer for my specific case.

I am trying to make software for managing stores. Lets say I have a storehouse that can keep lots of products from different types. Lets focus for now on types Tech (laptops, mobile phones, PCs) and Clothes ( jackets, dresses, shoes).

I also have different sections in my storehouse for storing Tech products and Clothes. Since I have lots of different types of products and I think that one table wont satisfy my needs. However if I was to create new table for every type then I would need to hold this products location. This means that I will have lots of tables to check for products when collecting data for the storehouse and doesnot seem as the best solution.

If I was to use MongoDB I could create one table product and not worry about it since I can add properties as I wish and have another collection called storehouse with sections which have products. However in MySQL database I don't think that having big tables with lots of properties is the best solution.

The biggest problem is that I have full freedom to create the database as I see fit as long as it is with MySQL Server. I don't have physical storehouse. This is a project for my uni where we need to create the software as if we had one. Meaning I can have as many sections as I wish and as many product types as I wish. This freedom means there are lots of options for me to create the database but none seem to be effective.

Should I create different tables for every category and store the products there? Should I have one table with the basic information (picture, name, description, price) and in others based on the id to hold the rest of the information? Should I have different sections as individual tables and one table storehouse which will hold every section? Should I create less tables but more compacted or separate everything into lots and lots of tables and relations between them?

What I am looking for is advice on how to make it good following the best practices. Thank you in advance!

And for last - please don't mark it as too broad because I think it isn't. If you however do - please leave a comment to explain why you think that is.

Comment: This is actually too broad. Coming up with concepts for your homework isn't what we're here for. SO is for solving particular programming problems and deciding on a database schema doesn't fit the bill as far as question criteria is concerned so your question probably will be closed but because I'm such a helpful so-and-so, I've provided an answer for you before that happens. Best of luck

Comment: It's also a primarily opinion-based question. There are many ways you could build this database and there isn't really a **right** or **wrong** way.

Comment: I am not a Db specialist, so I may say some fooleries, but I share you my experience. I worked on a project with the same goal. We had millions of products in the same table with a lots of columns (like 30 columns). In such scenarios, what is really important is how you set your indexes and how you query your data. Even with very large tables like this, if you join or filter only on indexes, the fetch (may be not the good term) won't depends on the table size and will be extremly quick.

Comment: It is too broad because as mentioned above, none of of can give you  one definite answer which can be judged by the others as right or wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to share some insight even though my first instinct was to vote to close the question. Stackoverflow isn't really the place to get help with conceptualizing your system. Strictly speaking, you should have all of this kind of stuff worked out before you come and ask here, and even then, [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be a better place once you have some code written up.

So the way I see it, you'll want at least 3 tables (Categories, Subcategories, Products).

- Categories table will be for "Clothes", "Tech", etc.
- Subcategories table will be for "Jackets, Dresses, Shoes" etc".
- Products will be the actual product detail.

To link the data, you'll have a column to reference a record in the other table similar to this:

```
Categories Table:
    Integer column "Id" - Primary Key, does not allow nulls
    varchar column "Name" - does not allow nulls

Subcategories Table:
    Integer column "Id" - Primary Key, does not allow nulls
    Integer column "CategoryId" Foreign Key references Categories.Id, does not allow nulls
    varchar column "Name" - does not allow nulls

Products Table:
    Integer Column "Id" - Primary Key, does not allow nulls
    Integer Column "SubcategoryId" Foreign Key references Subcategories.Id, does not allow nulls
    <the rest of your product information goes here>
```

You could add a Category column to your Products table as well but you should always specify a Subcategory. This will allow you to filter products by Category and Subcategory both.

This approach is about as simple as you can get but please next time actually try to do something before you ask.

Comment: How should I store the information for my product? Here is the tricky part - Some products have RAM, CPU (Tech) and others have material and size. If I was to create one table storing both I would need to have properties for both and each type will have the properties of the other set to null. If I was to have 10 categories...then that one table would have more than 50 properties and each product will store all of them set to 'null'. This doesnt seem as the best practice.

Comment: I'd suggest creating several varchar columns in the Products table called "CustomField1", "CustomField2", etc. and putting specific data like RAM, size, whatever, into there. Its up to you how you want to read that data out

Comment: Otherwise, you can create a kind of `Dictionary` table to add specific product type properties but I would not recommand it because it would involve magic string to retrieve them. Unless you maintain in your code an enum to match each property. But anyway, that would not be pratical to use. The best option in my opinion, though tedious, is a separate table for each product type.

Comment: In the project I was, they decided to host every properties in the main product table. Which means a lots of nullable column. That works too but I found it very painful to use (numeric columns are mapped to Nullable type in C# for example and it is very painful to manage in code).

Comment: Hah wait until you work on one where they do that, but call the columns Number1 to Number10, String1 to String10, and whats in what changes based on a type column. You'll love what they have....

Comment: @fharreau you could have a table called RamSpecs, for example which links to the Products table and contains only information specific to RAM

Comment: @Rob because I've been there where I'm sitting looking at a problem and have no idea how to solve it. Because I think its better to provide a little bit of info even if its off topic, than to just ignore the question. At least this way he's got somewhere to start.

Comment: "Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which..." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

SQL is just not a good way to do this, you could hide it all behind an ORM which would give you the polymorphism you want from the code end. 
Optimising and using the database directly will be painful though.

There's an entity attribute value scheme, but very few have enjoyed the results of that...

A compromise design is multiple tables, but only for the extra information. Make anything you want to query cross product category on, e.g. price or quantity generic, put the extras in their own table (or an xml snippet, or serialised name value or some such). This is pretty much what an ORM would do.

Too hard to advise you from here, there are a lot of ways to skin this cat. Also whatever design you come up with, I guarantee the one you choose will end up looking a poor one when some future requirement comes in.

ORM route for me, and plan on always accessing the data via it.

Comment: When dealing with large table, using the ORM approach can be very difficult. The queries built by the engine won't target just the indexes and the response time can be very disadvantageous. Generally, you can't even define your own indexes. Or that requires to know exactly how works the ORM.

Comment: Yep, as soon as you start getting too clever, it can go very painful. Thing is somewhere its going to get painful and messy, code or database. You thought about hiding the database end behind stored procedures?

Comment: Personnally, I don't like stored procedures. They were using that on my project and the performance was very good. But I stopped counting the issues caused by an old procedure we forgot to update, etc. I think (never tested in practice) that you could get very good performance (may be not as good as with procedure but good enough) by querying yourself your database without hinding behind an ORM repository. Entity Framework allows the dev to write queries without using all its magic repository stuff. That could be the proper mix ? (As I said, never tested myself)

Comment: Shrugs, All designs are compromises at least don't be plastering SQL all over your app.

Comment: Not all over the app, just in the Data Access Layer, behind an interface. You can start by implementing it with your favorite ORM and when the performance starts weaken, then switch to a custom SQL query. In my opinion, you cannot compromise with performance when there is a user behind the screen waiting for a query responding after 5min :). But I would always use ORM if the performance are good and use Stored Procedure only any other solution failed !

Comment: I'll go with that, ORM first, or a dll datalayer and simple DTOs to pass to it for the CRUD